# Problem with file permissions in shared directory under /srv between OS X and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, osx, acl

I'm setting up some folders where any user in the `users` group can collaborate on files, on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server.

It seems that `users` on my machine have no problems editing each other's files (I have configured ACL group permission). However, we have `users` connecting through the Mac OS X Finder `Network` window, and these users are not able to edit files created on the Ubuntu box, nor vice versa. They are able to create and edit their own files. I can see their created files, but not edit them. They don't appear to respect the ACL mask.

Any idea what might be causing this?

-- Updates: Responses to Questions --

Joseph R - I don't know the answer to your question. I have used `setfacl` to configure the appropriate permissions for the `users` group, and I (likely wrongly) assumed that OS X would respect these settings.

robbat2 - Last night I determined that I was using AFP, which might actually be the root of the issue (I'm using `netatalk` on Ubuntu).

I'm beginning to think that the solution will be to force users to use NFS. Would this be the prudent choice?

Comment: Mac probably explicitly sets group permissions to 0 instead of respecting a more normal linux/unix umask.

Comment: How are you sharing the user credentials (authentication, group membership,...) between the two machines?

Comment: How are you sharing the files? NFS, Samba, something else?

Comment: Are you using setfacl? Does mac use this type of acl?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the shares are set to writable in samba's configuration.

at the end of your /etc/samba/smb.conf you should see your shares. Set it to the bellow:

```
[someshare]
     writeable=yes
```

Run a `testparam` then `/etc/init.d/samba force-reload`

Comment: Hello Luke, does the 'network' sidebar in OSX default to samba? I figured it was using apple file protocol.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I missed that update. You can try to use samba or NFS if you want, but I'm sure you can get this working. Here's a thought, try using the most restrictive permissions on one file (chmod 0000 file) and see if you can still edit these files.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to add 'perm:0770' to each share line in /etc/netatalk. I just added each folder separately to manage the group permissions. There might be a better solution, however.

More: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1580562